# unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UND_TBS'

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to insert data from `table1` to an existing table say `table2`.
table1 has 30 million records. Used the below command to insert the data. Got the given error after some time.

```
insert into TABLE2 (select * from TABLE1)
Error at Command Line:31 Column:0
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UND_TBS'
30036. 00000 -  "unable to extend segment by %s in undo tablespace '%s'"
```

It shown that, `the specified undo tablespace has no more space available.`

Before retrying the operation, what can I do. Is there any other workarounds available to insert the data successfully?

Comment: You need to add space to the undo tablespace (e.g. by adding another data file)

Comment: Simply create a new empty data file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@a_horse_with_no_name commented out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405344/unable-to-extend-segment-by-8-in-undo-tablespace-und-tbs#comment37752617_24405344),

I have created a new data file keeping the `autoextend` on.

```
alter tablespace UND_TBS add datafile   '/path/my_data_file.dbf' size 7168M autoextend on;
```

The path can be identified by,

```
select file_name from dba_data_files where tablespace_name ='UND_TBS';
```

Ans you can get the maximum/free size of the tablespace by,

```
SELECT b.tablespace_name,
  tbs_size SizeMb,
  a.free_space FreeMb
FROM
  (SELECT tablespace_name,
    ROUND(SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 ,2) AS free_space
  FROM dba_free_space
  GROUP BY tablespace_name
  ) a,
  (SELECT tablespace_name,
    SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 AS tbs_size
  FROM dba_data_files
  GROUP BY tablespace_name
  ) b
WHERE a.tablespace_name(+)=b.tablespace_name;
```

Comment: Did your issue get resolved? You may also want to check the size of TABLE1 and consider other options to make a copy - such as create TABLE2 with the NOLOGGING option. You could also check the activity on the database and see why the UNDO tablespace got full.

Comment: Yes @JosephB: The issue got resolved.When I checked I could see the `my_data_file.dbf`is used as part of DB